# Run IEnumerator functions once counter hits certain number

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scripting, ienumerator

All! I'm trying to run a process once my counter hits a certain number.

I currently have this part of code on my Update function:

```
if (counter == 17)
{
  // must call process here
}
```

This is the process I want to run

```
   private void CallProcess()
   {
     StartCoroutine(StartProcess());
   }
```

This is the whole code for the IEnumerator

```
 private IEnumerator StartProcess()
    {
       yield return StartCoroutine (Process1()); //once done, a bool here is set to true
      if (proccess1_done)
      {
        yield return StartCoroutine (Process2());
        if (process2_done)
        {
          process1_done = false;
          process2_done = false;
        }
      }

    }
```

I encounter problems when I just call CallProcess() inside my update bc it gets called over and over again. Any advice on how I should modify my code would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why not just use a bool like you you did it with `process1_done`? It'd be something like `bool isStartingProcess`

Comment: As @SwiftingDuster said why not use a bool? Turn off the `isStartingProcess` when entering the call ie in `CallProcess()` and enable it again at the end of coroutine, that should solve the problem.

Comment: I already tried if (counter == 17) { isStartProcess = true} if (isProcess true) { CallProcess();} but it seems like it's all overlapping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't call the StartCoroutine in update. Instead, wrap the boolean in a property so when it is changed or set, you can also call the StartCoroutine.

Let's say counter is the one that sets it:

```
private IEnumerator coroutine = null;
private int counter = 0;
public int Counter 
{
    get{ return this.counter; }
    set
    {
         this.counter =  value;
         if(this.counter == conditionValue)
         { 
             if(this.coroutine != null){ return; } // already running
             this.coroutine = StartProcess();
             StartCoroutine(this.coroutine); }
    }
}
```

and for your coroutine:

```
private IEnumerator StartProcess()
{
   yield return StartCoroutine (Process1()); 
   yield return StartCoroutine (Process2());
}
```

you don't really need to check whether Process 1 is done since your coroutine is already waiting for it to be done before continuing.

if you need to check for something inside process 1 for process 2 to run, here is a solution:

```
private IEnumerator StartProcess()
{
   bool condition = false;
   yield return StartCoroutine (Process1(ref condition));
   if(condition == false){ yield break; } 
   yield return StartCoroutine (Process2());
   this.coroutine = null;
}

private IEnumerator Process1(ref bool condition)
{
     // some code
     yield return null;
     // more code
     condition = true; // or false
}
```

Comment: thanks for the clarification! let me try this real quick